# Mensaje según hora del día no funciona VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Tengo una funcionalidad en mi sistema que muestra un mensaje según la hora del día, pero no funciona

```
Dim msg As String
Dim horaActual As String
horaActual =  System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")

If horaActual >= "24:00" and horaActual <= "12:00" Then
   msg = "Buenos Días"
ElseIf horaActual >= "12:01" and horaActual <= "19:00" Then
   msg = "Buenas Tardes"
ElseIf horaActual >= "19:01" and horaActual <= "23:59" Then
   msg = "Buenas Noches" End code
End If
```

Obtengo la hora del sistema (9:16) y debería entrar en la primer condición pero no entra a ninguna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion es que al parecer las 24:00 Hrs son en realidad las 00:00 Hrs

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma de comparar las fechas, es con la expresión de `DateTime` con el signo `#`, puede ser así:

```
    Dim msg As String
    Dim horaActual As String
    horaActual = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")

    If horaActual >= #12:00:00 PM# And horaActual <= #12:00:00 AM# Then
        msg = "Buenos Días"
    ElseIf horaActual >= #12:01:00 AM# And horaActual <= #7:00:00 PM# Then
        msg = "Buenas Tardes"
    ElseIf horaActual >= #7:01:00 PM# And horaActual <= #11:59:00 PM# Then
        msg = "Buenas Noches"
    End If
```

Te dejo una captura de su funcionamiento:
[image: Fechas]

Comment: +1 Interesante, yo solía compararlos con el valor en millisegundos, eso implicaba convertir el string a millisegundos para realizar la comparación. =|

Answer (score 1):

El problema que noto es que quieres comparar rangos usando string, cuando deberias usar numeros

Podrias convertir la hora al formato militar (que seguro habras escuchado en muchas peliculas) en donde las 12:00 hs son las 1200.
Para esto tomas la hora y la conviertes a numero.

```
Dim msg As String
Dim horaActual As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm"))

If horaActual >= 2400 and horaActual <= 1200 Then
   msg = "Buenos Días"
ElseIf horaActual >= 1201 and horaActual <= 1900 Then
   msg = "Buenas Tardes"
ElseIf horaActual >= 1901 and horaActual <= 2359 Then
   msg = "Buenas Noches" End code
End If
```

Comment: No funcionó. sigue sin entrar a la condición correspondiente, le cambie la primera condición a Or en lugar de And y si entro pero creo que no debería ser así para lo que requiero verdad?

Comment: creo que la condición esta mal ya que por ejemplo en este instante me obtengo del sistema 1040 y en la primer condición comparo que hora sea mayor a 2400, entonces no se como estaría la condicion

Answer (score 0):

Mira, replique tu código cambiando los `msn`por `Label1.Text =` (para replicarlo en forma fácil) y funciona bien:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim horaActual As String
        horaActual = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")

        If horaActual >= "24:00" And horaActual <= "12:00" Then
            Label1.Text = "Buenos Días"
        ElseIf horaActual >= "12:01" And horaActual <= "19:00" Then
            Label1.Text = "Buenas Tardes"
        ElseIf horaActual >= "19:01" And horaActual <= "23:59" Then
            Label1.Text = "Buenas Noches"
        End If

        Label2.Text = horaActual

    End Sub
```

El Label2 es el de arriba y contiene la hora actual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]